# Method of Infinite Images -Placing a point charge between two concentric conducting shells

Tags: electrostatics

I tried to find the induced charge on two grounded conducting spherical shells due to a charge place in between them. Using method of images, I get a diverging series for the total induced charge on the outer shell, yet we know that physically that induced charge must be finite. Furthermore, by abusing some notations and breaking some rules, I was able to achieve the correct answers but I want to know what exactly is going wrong in the approach, and how am I able to "tame the infinite"? Details are as follows.

There are two concentric conducting shells of radius $R_1$ and $R_2$ ($R_1$<$R_2$). A positive charge $q$ is  placed somewhere between the two shells at a distance $r$ from center($R_1<r<R_2$). All the distances from now on will be measured from the center.

[image]

I used method of Images to solve for total charge $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ induced at the inner and outer conductor respectively.
I started by putting an Image charge $q_1 = -\frac{R_1}{r}q$ at a distance $d_1 = \frac{R_1^2}{r}$ from the center. Then placing a secondary image charge which is induced by this image charge outside the outer shell. Charge's value will be $q'_1 = -\frac{R_2}{d_1}q_1 = \frac{R_2}{R_1}q = \beta q$ and at a distance $d'_1 = \frac{R_2^2}{d_1} =\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)^2r = \beta^2r$ . Where I defined,
\begin{equation}
\beta \equiv \frac{R_2}
{R_1}\end{equation}
Note that, $\beta > 1$. We continue to put subsequent image charged forming an infinite series of image charges inside and outside the sphere. I am using primed symbols for images outside $R_2$ and unprimed symbols for images inside $R_1$ .

[image]

Writing the all distances and charges, we find that for inside ($r<R_1$)
\begin{equation}
q_n = \frac{-qR_2}{r}\frac{1}{\beta^n}; (n = 1, 2, ...)\\
 d_n = \frac{R_2^2}{r}\frac{1}{\beta^{2n}} 
\end{equation}
and for outside ($r>R_2$)
\begin{equation}
q'_n = \beta^n q \\
 d'_n = \beta^{2n}r
\end{equation}
We also have to take care of the other series of infinite charges that will form when we start by placing the first image charge outside and follow from there. To distinguish this series from the previous one, I will use uppercase letters. Then,  For inside ($r<R_1$)
\begin{equation}
Q_n = \frac{q}{\beta^n}\\
 D_n = \frac{r}{\beta^{2n}} 
\end{equation}
and for outside ($r>R_2$)
\begin{equation}
Q'_n = -\frac{qR_1}{r}\beta^n \\
 d'_n = \frac{R_1^2}{r}\beta^{2n}
\end{equation}
To find the total charge on the $R_2$ shell, I will need to do a summation
\begin{equation}
 Q_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(q'_n + Q'_n) = q\left(1-\frac{R_1}{r}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta^n
\end{equation}
Since, $\beta >1$ the sum diverges. But the sum for $Q_1$ converges, so we may carry that out
\begin{equation}
 Q_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(q_n + Q_n) = q\left(1-\frac{R_2}{r}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\beta^n} = -q\left(\frac{R_2}{r}-1\right)\frac{R_1}{R_2-R_1}
\end{equation}
Since, total induced charge must be $Q_1+Q_2 = -q$, therefore I have an alternative way of finding $Q_2$ because I have found $Q_1$. By this I find
\begin{equation}
 Q_2 = -q\left(1-\frac{R_1}{r}\right)\frac{R_2}{R_2-R_1}
\end{equation}

Why am I getting a diverging sum with one method but an perfectly finite answer with another? As an additional consistency check, this problem was solved in Introduction to Electrodynamics David J. Griffiths Fourth Editions problem 3.44(d) using Green's Reciprocity theorem and answers of $Q_2$ and $Q_1$ obtained are exactly the same as I have obtained here.

Even more mysteriously, If I were to blindly assume $\beta < 1$ for calculating $Q_2$ in the diverging (now converging sum), the problem term becomes

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta^n = \beta + \beta^2 + \beta^3 +... = -\frac{1}{\beta - 1}
\end{equation}
This is complete non sense for $\beta>1$
which is the case here. But yet, if I substitute $\beta =R_2/R_1 $ anyway, I end up with the correct result for $Q_2$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
 Q_2 = -q\left(1-\frac{R_1}{r}\right)\frac{R_2}{R_2-R_1}
\end{equation}
Since the induced charge on outer shell should be negative, the extra negative sign introduced by this "wrong" sum actually makes the sign of the answer correct as well, elsewise, I'd have a positive net induced charge at $R_2$ because the diverging sum is obviously positive.

This is reminding me of
\begin{equation}
1+2+3+4+... = -\frac{1}{12}
\end{equation}

Are there some analytic continuations of this sum of geometric progression $\sum_n \beta^n $ involved here, that are hidden somewhere in my analysis?